# Filtering data by getting only distinct columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query

```
SELECT *
FROM tblMyTable
```

that returns these results:

```
ID | TypeID | Name
----------------------------------
1DF6EAA0-D0EC-4E4D-9E6B-1779F0E42A82 | 8518A117-F032-61E6-EF15-1917F5B4E795 | AAA
7BB627EC-16CE-40DA-9CC0-A1861277988D | 8518A117-F032-61E6-EF15-1917F5B4E795 | BBB
25B68C46-C03E-4C1F-94BC-7A371B2F1AC3 | DBE7A7EF-5B97-448C-0D2E-5C0C2155A2FA | CCC
AD1A8990-4A57-4F95-BCBD-6112111782B0 | CAE4D031-2C02-2BB8-5D15-FF865A24AD55 | DDD
94C24A30-18EF-471E-8984-6D165EAB566B | A7FE61B5-F4EB-6286-D3A6-72E458D8745C | EEE
D3A7F2E2-DAAF-B991-E41D-105EBB071323 | A7FE61B5-F4EB-6286-D3A6-72E458D8745C | FFF
3EBE7F2F-A05E-FC02-4AE3-27DF6D9A524E | A7FE61B5-F4EB-6286-D3A6-72E458D8745C | GGG
```

I'd like to filter the results so that there are only distinct TypeIds, so that the results returned are:

```
ID | TypeID | Name
----------------------------------
1DF6EAA0-D0EC-4E4D-9E6B-1779F0E42A82 | 8518A117-F032-61E6-EF15-1917F5B4E795 | AAA
25B68C46-C03E-4C1F-94BC-7A371B2F1AC3 | DBE7A7EF-5B97-448C-0D2E-5C0C2155A2FA | CCC
AD1A8990-4A57-4F95-BCBD-6112111782B0 | CAE4D031-2C02-2BB8-5D15-FF865A24AD55 | DDD
94C24A30-18EF-471E-8984-6D165EAB566B | A7FE61B5-F4EB-6286-D3A6-72E458D8745C | EEE
```

How can I change my query to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can apply [`row_number()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx):

```
select id, typeid, name
from
(
  select id, typeid, name,
    row_number() over(partition by typeid order by typeid, name) rn
  from yourtable
) src
where rn =1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/578f0/6)

Comment: just for information: you could also use `rank()` or `dense_rank()` instead of `row_number()` in this case. See differences [here](http://thehobt.blogspot.de/2009/02/rownumber-rank-and-denserank.html)